# Read data from reviews on the Daraz website

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This code perfectly runs in other URL like getting a product or paragraph. But cannot able to read **reviews**.

```
import csv
from lib2to3.pgen2 import driver
from operator import itemgetter
from re import template
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('H:/PythonMechineLearnning/WebScrape/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe') 

url = 'https://www.daraz.com.bd/products/1-livingtex-_-i183964360-s1169754856.html?spm=a2a0e.searchlist.list.2.6a801fbaMbkK8g&search=1'
driver.get(url)
print(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
result = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'content'})

print(result[0])
```

**Error**
`IndexError: list index out of range`
cannot able to read data

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is in the `HTML`. There's an embedded `JSON` there so you don't really need `chromdriver` nor `bs4`.

You can get the reviews with plain `requests`.

Here's how:

```py
import json
import re

import requests

url = "https://www.daraz.com.bd/products/1-livingtex-_-i183964360-s1169754856.html?spm=a2a0e.searchlist.list.2.6a801fbaMbkK8g&search=1"

data = (
    json.loads(
        re.search(
            r"app\.run\((.*)\);",
            requests.get(url).text,
            re.MULTILINE,
        ).group(1)
    )
)
reviews = data["data"]["root"]["fields"]["review"]

print(f'{reviews["ratings"]}\n{"-" * 80}')

for review in reviews["reviews"]:
    print(f'{review["reviewer"]} -> {review["reviewContent"]}\n')
```

Output:

```sh
{'average': 3.7, 'rateCount': 83, 'reviewCount': 68, 'scores': [47, 7, 7, 4, 18]}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Asif -> ৪৯ টাকায় কেনা হয়েছে। খুবই ভালো মানের পন্য। চাইলে সবাই নিতে পারেন। ডেলিভারি অনেক দ্রুত ছিল, ধন্যবাদ সেলারকে।

Mushfiqur R. -> ছবির প্রোডাক্ট আর এই প্রোডাক্টটা কি সেম? I don’t think so. বাট জিনিস টা পরে কমফোর্টেবল আছে।

1***3 -> I've ordered Blue Color Boxer XL size from Livingtex but they have sent me wrong color product (Black). Earlier Livingtex done this type of mistake with me. Is this a professionalism? How can they do this type of mistake repeatedly? This is So Sad.

P***. -> সাইজ বিবরণ অনুযায়ী ঠিক ছিল কিন্তু কাপড়ের মান ভালো না। Just দুই দিন পরার পরই পরতে গিয়ে পায়ে লেগে ছিঁড়ে যায়। কাপড় খুবই নরম এবং খারাপ। কোমরের রাবারও বেশ লুজ।

Alamin K. -> ceyesi M dise L no problem product return disi product amk a diya diya hoyse abr cashbake o paye gesi full taka thanks daraz
```